# Fluid icon relative to parent

Tags: css

In my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TgW2D/5/), There are two buttons with icons. Currently I am using fixed `width` and `height`for these icons, how can I use `percentage` relative to the parent size of these icons? Example: 80%?

Fixed width and height of my icons:

```
    .gc_footer_nix_icon_img, .gc_footer_use_icon_img {
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class='gc_container'>
    <div class='gc_gift'>
        <div class='gc_gift_inner'>
            <div class='gc_amount'>$100 Amount</div>
            <div class='gc_subtitle'>Test subtitle</div>
            <div class='gc_hr'></div>
            <div class='gc_terms'>Test terms</div>
            <div class='gc_footer'>
                <div class='gc_footer_expiry'>Test Date</div>
                <div class='gc_footer_use_nix'>
                    <div class='gc_footer_use'>
                        <div class='gc_footer_button_wrapper'>
                            <div class='gc_footer_use_txt'>Use</div>
                            <div class='gc_footer_use_icon'>
                                <img class='gc_footer_use_icon_img' src='https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/849x565q90/833/uua2.jpg' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='gc_footer_nix'>
                        <div class='gc_footer_button_wrapper'>
                            <div class='gc_footer_nix_txt'>Nix</div>
                            <div class='gc_footer_nix_icon'>
                                <img class='gc_footer_nix_icon_img' src='https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/849x565q90/833/uua2.jpg' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.gc_gift {
    margin-top:1.5%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:1.5%;
    height: auto;
    width: 97%;
    position:relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    border:1px solid #D1D1D1;
}
.gc_gift_inner {
    font-size:1em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border:0px solid #D1D1D1;
    display:table;
    margin-top:2.5%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:2.5%;
    height: auto;
    width: 95%;
    position:relative;
    overflow: scroll;
    webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.gc_amount {
    color: red;
    font-size:2em;
}
.gc_subtitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #707070;
}
.gc_hr {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border-color: #D1D1D1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}
.gc_terms {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #707070;
}
.gc_footer {
    width: 95%;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}
.gc_footer_expiry {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 40%;
    color: #707070;
    border: 0px solid yellow;
}
.gc_footer_use_nix {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60%;
    border:0px solid green;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: right;
}
.gc_footer_use {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #3F6EB6;
    border-radius: 1px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    border:0px solid red;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
.gc_footer_use_txt {
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.gc_footer_use_icon {
    text-align: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.gc_footer_nix {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #D61920;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 0x solid green;
    padding: 2%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
.gc_footer_nix_txt {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid blue;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.gc_footer_nix_icon {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid yellow;
    width: 50%;
}
.gc_footer_button_wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    border: 0px solid blue;
}
.gc_container {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    height: auto;
    width: 90%;
    display:table;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid #D1D1D1;
}
.gc_amount, .gc_subtitle, .gc_terms, .gc_footer {
    border: 0px solid green;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:0.3em;
    padding-bottom:0.3em;
}
.gc_footer_nix_icon_img, .gc_footer_use_icon_img {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;;

}
```

Comment: You just set `width: 80%` and `height: 80%`. But the parent to the images do not have a set width and height, you need to set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set width to `gc_footer_nix` and `gc_footer_use` , and then you'll be able to set the width on the images . Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TgW2D/7/